# definition of off_t with c99

Tags: c, c99, large-files

I'm trying to port some code from windows to linux, but I'm having difficulty with support for large files. off_t seems to be defined when gcc is run with -std=c89 but not for -std=c99. Even a trivial test case will not compile:

```
#define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    off_t x = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

It really doesn't seem like this should be difficult (in fact, it's not on all other operating systems). Anyone have any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 3):

The type `off_t` is not defined by ISO C; it's defined by POSIX.

I get

```
error: unknown type name ‘off_t’
```

if I compile with either `-std=c90`, `-std=c99`, or `-std=c11`. That's to be expected, since those options specify conformance to the relevant C standard. Since you're compiling C code that doesn't conform to any of those C standards, you shouldn't use those options.

I find that `off_t` is defined if I compile with `-std=gnu90`, `-std=gnu99`, or `-std=gnu11`.

Also, `off_t` is the return type of the `lseek` function, whose man page on my system says it requires:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
```

You should add those.